# Score not increasing after the user has scored 1 in Quiz App. How do i fix?

Tags: java, android, radio-button

Its a Quiz App, It has multiple options for the correct answer and radio buttons as the options, when clicked on the correct radio button the score must increase by 1 unless of how many times the radio button is clicked and  this also works after the "next" button is clicked.The problem here for me is that the score does not increase after it has increased once. It stops progressing after the user has answered one question correctly. How can I fix this?

I have tried changing the conditions of how it runs, it still does not work for me.

```
RadioButton getClickedButton;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton getClickedButton;
Button quit,btnNext;    
private int score=0; 
boolean clicked=true;

//for button Next

  btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            radioGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            getClickedButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

            try {
                if(getClickedButton.getText().equals(answer) ){
                    if(clicked){
                    score++;
                    updateScore(score);
                    clicked=false;
                }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

                if (questionNumber < totalQuestion) {
                    updateQuestion();
                    radioGroup.clearCheck(); //to clear the last checked item
                } else {
                    resultIntent();
                }

        }
    });
   //for button Next

  //quit button

    quit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        resultIntent();
    }
});
 //quit button
} 

//Intent for result Activity

   public void resultIntent(){
    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ResultActivity.class);
    Bundle dataSend = new Bundle();
    dataSend.putInt("SCORING",score);
    dataSend.putInt("TOTAL",totalQuestion);
    i.putExtras(dataSend);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
  }
//Intent for result Activity

 //to update the score

  public void updateScore(int mscore){
    showScore.setText("" +  mscore);
}
//to update score
```

Comment: Where is declaration for "clicked" variable?

Comment: the `clicked` variable is missing from your code and its value is probably `false`, which is why the code under the `if` block isn’t executed.

Comment: No the declaration is there, I just forgot to mention it in the code and it is declared as boolean clicked=true;

Comment: Did you add `radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener()` code? If yes, please post it.

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology why should I add this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this `clicked=true;` above `if (questionNumber < totalQuestion)`
like this

```
clicked=true;
if (questionNumber < totalQuestion)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     if(getClickedButton.getText().equals(answer) ){
                if(clicked){
                score++;
                updateScore(score);
                clicked=false;
            }
     }
```

You're setting the "clicked" variable to "false" and never back to true. You'll enter the if(clicked) the first time because you defined it as "true" for the first time, than you're setting its value to "false" and it remains "false", so that from the second time that you click on the button, you will not enter the "if" because the condition is "false".

Since part of the code is missing and it is not very clear where you're gonna use "clicked = false", the only thing that i can suggest is remove "clicked = false" or insert "clicked = true" in a different part of the code, after you do your checks.